# Dynamically switch global CSS for Angular8 app (client branding)

Tags: css, dynamic, angular8

I want to dynamically switch Angulars global CSS files based on which client is connecting. This will be used for client-branding purposes, including fonts, colors, photos, headers, footers, button-styles, etc.

Each client has provided us with a CSS file, which we need to integrate into our app. We have hundreds of clients.

Current solution is to try and override the CSS of individual components at load. This is bad because it adds a lot of boilerplate:

Html:

```
<link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/stylesheets/{{cclientCode}}.css">
```

ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.clientCode.subscribe(clientCode => this.clientCode = clientCode);
  }
```

My workaround isn't working because the **link** html is called before the {{}} has a chance to load in the value.

I'm also not motivated to fix my workaround because its just that -a workaround. Instead, I want to implement something that works globally, without any per-component boilerplate.

What I want is the ability to dynamically switch the *global* Angular style for each client. So something like:

```
"styles": [
              "src/assets/stylesheets/angular_style.css",
              "src/assets/stylesheets/client_style.css"
]
```

Where client_style.css is served differently to each client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that I think is workable. It definitely has issues though, so if anyone has their own answer, please still share!

First, I added a clientCode String field to SessionDataService, a global service I use to move component-agnostic data around my app:

```
export class SessionDataService {
  clientCode: BehaviorSubject<String>;

  constructor(){
    this.clientCode = new BehaviorSubject('client_default');
  }

  setClientCode(value: String) {
    this.clientCode.next(value);
  }
}
```

Then, inside app.component.ts, I added a BehaviorSubject listener to bring in the value of clientCode dynamically:

```
  public clientCode: String;
  constructor(private service : SessionDataService) {
    this.service.clientCode.subscribe(clientCode => this.clientCode = clientCode);
  }
```

Next, I added a wrapper around my entire app.component.html:

```
<div [ngClass]="clientCode">
--> ALL app components go here (including <router-outlet>)
</div>
```

So at this point, I've created a system that dynamically adds client-code CSS classes to my components, including all children :)

Finally, I just have to write CSS rules:

```
.ClientOne p {
  color: red;
}

.ClientOne .btn {
  background-color: red;
}

.ClientTwo.dashboard {
  height: 15%;
}
```

I hope this helps somebody! Essentially the "trick" here is to add a ngClass that wraps the entire app, and then justify all client-specific CSS rules with their client code.